# How to customize KeyCloak auth flows based on requested scope

Tags: authentication, oauth, keycloak, scopes

I'm trying to configure the KeyCloak Browser Flow to allow users requesting `scope1` to use a user/password form, and users requesting `scope2` to be required to use the User/password form plus an OTP. My question is two-part:

1. Am I not understanding something properly - I am surprised I have to code this myself and it's not already available in Keycloak
2. Will this described approach work?

I do not want to make this conditional on the user, but instead on the scope being requested. From what I can tell, to make this work I need to implement a custom `ConditionalAuthenticator` and then configure approximately  like this, replacing the `Condition - User Configured` with my own implementation.

[image: Example of per-scope configuration]

Comment: Would it be a possibility of use roles instead of scopes?

Comment: Sadly no, what I need is the authentication flow to change based on whatever the caller requested. The caller has the right to request any of the possible scopes (they have all of the necessary roles)

Comment: I'm interested in this question if i get an answer then i comment